# Can't create MySite because one already exists

Tags: my-site

I am getting the following error message when I try to open up My Site for the first time.

**Your personal site cannot be created because it already exists with your user name.  Please contact your administrator.**

I am the only person on our network with my user name but I used to have two of them due to a federated domain situation.  I think that I may have pulled up the My Site using the other domain name once.  Now that I'm using my normal domain name it is hitting a conflict.

Is the correct resolution to this to simply delete the site that is there (there is no content to my knowledge worth saving) and give it a chance to create properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Central Administration, go to Application Management and click the Delete Site Collection link.  Select the proper web application from the drop down and find your My Site.  Delete it (or both of them).  Go back to a Sharepoint site and click on the My Site link and it should provision a new one.

This is assuming you're talking about 2007.  In 2010 the steps are probably different due to the GUI redesign, but the premise is still the same, find the site collection(s) and delete them.

Comment: Ultimately we ended up deleting the old site and allowing it to re-create.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "Site Naming Format" section of the "My Site Settings" page within the SSP Admin site to resolve conflicts like this... Choose the middle option:

> User name (resolve conflicts by using domain_username)

This should allow you to create a new MySite without conflicting with your existing one

Answer (score -3):

You can try to delete it from cental admin (Site Collections) however you should verify whether it's exactly your site.

Or go to the SP content database and query all the sites.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [FullUrl],[Id] FROM [dbo].[Sites]
```

Then you can delete that site. Not recommended but should work

Comment: Querying the databases is not supported and is bad practice.  Other options exist to find that information in more supported formats, STSADM and Powershell for example.

Comment: Agreed, however I've mentioned that it's not recommended and suggested deleting through Central Admin first.

Comment: You should at least add `NOLOCK` to that query to prevent it from causing locking issues.

Comment: Never update the SQL tables in SharePoint, use the PowerShell cmdlets for any OM changes.